# Proper way to create and end trace spans in express / nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, opentracing, open-telemetry

I am experimenting on trying [Opentelemetry.js](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js) nodejs/express library and was trying to rewrite the [reviews application](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/samples/bookinfo/src/reviews) of the `bookinfo` [Sample](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/) from Istio.

I followed the tracer configurations as given in the [example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/blob/main/examples/express/tracer.js):

And my request handler as:

```
router.get('/:productIdStr', function(req, res, next) {
    starsReviewer1 = -1
    starsReviewer2 = -1
      var productId = parseInt(req.params.productIdStr)
      tracer = req.app.locals.tracer
    
      api.context.with(api.propagation.extract(api.ROOT_CONTEXT, req.headers),async () => {
        //---
       var returnedData=""
       span = {}
        Promise.all(
          [ function(){
            span = req.app.locals.tracer.startSpan('calculate-reviews', {
              kind: 1, // server
              attributes: { star_colour: starColor },    
            });
            let promise;
            api.context.with(api.setSpan(api.context.active(), span),async () => {
              additionalHeaders = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
              function addHeader(value, index, array) {
                if (typeof req.headers[value] !== 'undefined' && req.headers[value] !== null){
                  additionalHeaders[value] = req.headers[value]} 
              }
              headersToPropogate.forEach(addHeader)
              api.propagation.inject(api.context.active(),additionalHeaders)
              requstPath='http://'+ratingsService +":"+ratingsServicePort + "/ratings/" + productId
              //GetRatings
              // Make HTTP Call to the ratings service here.
              promise = axios.get(
                requstPath,
               {headers:additionalHeaders}
              )
              .then((res) => {
                log_info(span,"Get Ratings give value")
                span.addEvent('Data available from ratings ');
                returnedData=res.data
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                log_info(span,"Get Ratings did not give value, Using default Values")
                span.addEvent('Data not available from ratings ');
                console.error(error)
              })
              .finally(() => {
                span.end();
              });
    
            })
            return promise;
          }()]
        )
        .then(() => {
          if (returnedData !== ""){
            
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'application/json'})
            res.end(JSON.stringify(getJsonResponse(productId,returnedData.ratings.Reviewer1, returnedData.ratings.Reviewer1)))
          }
          else{
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'application/json'})
            res.end(JSON.stringify(getJsonResponse(productId,starsReviewer1, starsReviewer1)))
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'application/json'})
          res.end(JSON.stringify(getJsonResponse(productId,starsReviewer1, starsReviewer1)))
        })
        .finally(()=>{
          span.end()
        })
        
        })
      //---
    });
```

The issue I am facing is when I look at the traces generated it seems wrong:
[image]

The issues are:

- "calculate-reviews" span doesn't get closed
- How do I remove the "HTTP GET" that seems to be getting added automatically. I tried to override this is my tracer setting but it doesn't work. Rather a new `node-express-reviews-service` span seems to be getting created in addition to `HTTP GET`:

```
registerInstrumentations({
    tracerProvider: provider,
    instrumentations: [
      // Express instrumentation expects HTTP layer to be instrumented
      new HttpInstrumentation({
        requestHook: (span, request) => {
          span.updateName("node-express-reviews-service")
        }
    }),
      new ExpressInstrumentation(),
    ],
  });
```

- The span for the HTTP call to rating.default starts and ends before the `calculate-reviews` call. Ideally the span for `ratings.default` should start after `calculate-review` and end before. But in the image `calcualte-reviews` span starts and ends after `ratings.default`. What am I doing wrong and what is the right way of doing it?
- What is the error "clock skew adjustment disabled; not applying calculated delta of -53.6005ms" that I get under "calculate-reviews"
  [image]

Comment: Jesus this code needs some deep refactoring. How can you even read that? There are Promises with `.then()` mixed with `async` without `await` (so it's useless) inside functions inside callbacks inside a self-invoking function inside an array inside Promise.all inside a route handler O_o Also you `return promise` before it's defined (you define it inside an asynchronous callback, so it will be defined _after_ you return it)

Comment: What is `api.context.with`? It takes a callback function without an argument? So it returns nothing? But still takes a callback function? I don't get it. Also `Promise.all` has an array of just one Promise, so there's no need for Promise.all, one simple Promise will do

Comment: I'm trying to refactor and understand this code, but there are so many wrong and incomprehensible things. `api.context.with` doesn't return anything, but still takes a callback function? Why? `headersToPropogate` is undefined. Many variables are declared without `const`, which makes them global (`starsReviewer1`, `starsReviewer2` and `requstPath` for instance). `ratingsService` and `ratingsServicePort` are undefined. `starsReviewer2` is unused, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to refactor the code to make it more readable and understandable, hopefully that will be a good starting point to figure out what's wrong. But really, I don't understand what this is supposed to do, so I can't really debug it.

```
router.get('/:productIdStr', async (req, res) => {

    const starsReviewer1 = -1;
    const starsReviewer2 = -1;
    const productId = parseInt(req.params.productIdStr);
    const tracer = req.app.locals.tracer;

    await new Promise(resolve => api.context.with(api.propagation.extract(api.ROOT_CONTEXT, req.headers), resolve)); // Not sure what this does? It doesn't return anything?

    const span = req.app.locals.tracer.startSpan('calculate-reviews', {
        kind: 1, // server
        attributes: { star_colour: starColor },
    });

    await new Promise(resolve => api.context.with(api.setSpan(api.context.active(), span), resolve)); // Still not sure what this does, as it still doesn't return anything

    const additionalHeaders = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };

    headersToPropogate.forEach(value => { // headersToPropogate is undefined?
        if (typeof req.headers[value] !== 'undefined' && req.headers[value] !== null) {
            additionalHeaders[value] = req.headers[value]
        }
    });

    api.propagation.inject(api.context.active(), additionalHeaders); // No idea what this does, it doesn't seem to be asynchronous

    const requstPath = 'http://' + ratingsService + ":" + ratingsServicePort + "/ratings/" + productId;
    
    const returnedData = await axios.get(
        requstPath,
        { headers: additionalHeaders }
    ).data;

    if (returnedData !== "") {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'application/json' })
        res.end(JSON.stringify(getJsonResponse(productId, returnedData.ratings.Reviewer1, returnedData.ratings.Reviewer1)))
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'application/json' })
        res.end(JSON.stringify(getJsonResponse(productId, starsReviewer1, starsReviewer1)))
    }

    span.end(); // No idea what this is either
});
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for that helpful insight. You are right the code indeed needs quite a lot of refactoring...(And me learning the use proper use of promises).